# Uncountable many open non-degenerate intervals in R

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the set of all open intervals $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ in $R$ is uncountable but I am stuck at some point. 
My approach is to try to list the intervals in decreasing order of the length of the interval and put in the same sequence all that have the same length (by length I mean $b-a$) and then after this listing is done I want to find a new interval which is not in the list but I am not sure the idea will work. I would very much appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb R$ itself is uncountable?

Comment: You’re working much too hard: $(0,1)$ is an uncountable set, so $\{(0,x):0<x<1\}$ is ... ?

Comment: Yes, I can use the fact that $R$ is uncountable.

Comment: Ah I see, the set can be put into a bijection with (0,1).

Answer (score 1):

If R is uncountable, is the set $\{x \in R \| x > 0\}$ uncountable? What about the set $\{(0,x) \| x > 0 \}$?

Answer (score 0):

If at least you know that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, then you immediately conclude there are uncountably many intervals of the form $(x,x+1)$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$. Of course there are other intervals as well, but their cardinal remains uncountable.